# Disabling click event changing IsPressed on wpf checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, checkbox

Due to strange requirements, I need to disable the user's ability to change the IsChecked property of a checkbox through the click event.  I cannot disable the checkbox because right-clicking on it brings up a context menu that provides some options for the control including one that allows the user to control the checkbox's IsChecked state through some properties.  Is there a way to do this without creating a class that extends from this control?  This is in c# using the wpf checkbox.

Comment: How about handling the event and just calling `IsChecked = False` for every event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to try to set the `IsHitTestVisible` property to `false`.

Also do remember there's still the keyboard, so you might also want to set `IsTabStop` to `false` too.

Comment: Wow, that does work, I thought IsHitTestVisible would disable the context menu.  What exactly is this property doing?  I've used it before and never fully understood the documentation for it.  I ended up handling the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownevent to get a similar result before seeing your answer.  Also, much cleaner than the suggestion of toggling the value repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

Register for the Checked Event and set the IsChecked = !IsChecked.  Then when you need to change the checked property unregister for the Checked event change the value and then register again.  Not very nice but it should work without creating a new subclass

Comment: How would I unregister the checked event?  I went with the solution above, but this seems useful to know.

Comment: When changing the IsChecked property in code, you would remove the IsChecked eventHandler make your change and then set the handler again

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the context menu , by making the eventargs's handled property to true in contextmenuopening (bubble-up)event for checkbox control.

Comment: I wanted to enable the context menu, not disable it.  I'm a little confused by this response.